# How do I relate to huge auth.log and fail2ban.log files?

Tags: debian, logs

I have a question regarding log files on a Debian box.
I'm running a low volume PHP server, so most log files are small. However, `auth`, `fail2ban` (and `daemon`) are **huge**, even with log rotation.

```
2000K auth.log
 600K fail2ban.log
 200K daemon.log
   5K dpkg.log
   5K mail.log
   5K alternatives.log
   1K user.log
   1K kern.log
   1K php7.0-fpm.log
```

`fail2ban` contains only lots of lines with `INFO/NOTICE [sshd] Found (IP)` and `auth` contains various lines with `user unknown` and `Failed password`, presumably from automated attacks.

(SSH on the server has password logins turned off and is only accessible by RSA keys.)

I can't be reading through `auth.log` manually, and failed login attempts seems like information of no value, since it's happening all the time (and *did* fail), so how do I relate to these two files?

Can I configure them to contain less information? Is there a way to aggregate all the failures? Is there anything in them at all that would identify a more serious or actual break-in?

Or should I just ignore the log files and focus on general system hardening, and accept that the log files unfortunately will have a lot of noise in this day and age?

Comment: Consider changing from the default SSH 22 port to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the port the SSH servers runs on from 22 to another (higher) port, for instance 22222.

Automated attackers use the default port, so they won't be able to connect, and therefore won't be logged.

While this countermeasure is useless against a human attacker (a port scan of your server will give up the SSH port), is very effective against bots. Think of it as an additional layer of security.

Comment: That seems like a simple and effective fix to try first, though I should probably use a less obvious port since attackers may be on to this scheme and check 2222, 22222, etc. OK, so set `Port` in `sshd_config` and restart the daemon, but can this go wrong somehow? (Is there any chance I won't be able to log into my own machine?)

Comment: @forthrin, yes it may go wrong if you have FW rules that avoid access to the new port. Try running two ssh servers on different ports before removing the one on port 22.

Comment: I found `sshd` can listen on multiple ports like indicated in the link below. So I added a port, tried to log in, which worked, then removed port 22. Worked safe and sound. (I wasn't even forced out of my old port 22 shell either). Now to see if the log files diminish, which was the initial request. https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/change-ssh-to-listen-on-two-ports.47365/

Comment: What about `fail2ban`? Will that diminish from this trick too, or how do I make that less chatty, or relate to it on a regular basis?

Comment: There will be less login attempts, so `fail2ban` will contain fewer entries.  Note that you can also lower the log level to have less stuff logged -- from your post, `fail2ban` is logging at the INFO level.

Comment: Changed to `NOTICE` in `/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf` and reloaded the service. Will check the logs in a few days to see if they've grown comfortably small.